# Flask app deployment with gunicorn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

My web app has the following folder structure:

[image]

I am using gunicorn command as following, but I am getting the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 app:app
```

I also tried:
`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0  /application/app:app` , but I get the same error.

Could you plase help me with the right format/path for  gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

With my limited experience on gunicorn, I struggled with the same thing. Gunicorn commands do not take well to paths it seems, so just do

cd application/

then run your command again, it will work now.